# Toggle div question

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to toggle some divs and its not working, here is the js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){   

            $('#toggle_full').click(function(){         
                $('#full_size').removeClass('toggle');
                $('#thumb_list').addClass('toggle');
            });
        });

        $(function(){   

            $('#toggle_thumb').click(function(){            
                $('#thumb_list').removeClass('toggle');
                $('#full_size').addClass('toggle');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here are the anchors:

```
<div class="toggle_block">
        <a href="#" id="toggle_full"><img src="img/full_icon.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
        <a href="#" id="toggle_thumbs"><img src="img/thumbs_icon.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    </div>
```

Here is the class:

```
.toggle {
display: none;
}
```

Now where is the problem?

Comment: Not working as in?? Are there any errors?

Comment: No errors in firebug...

The links just don't fire the code when the link gets clicked.

Comment: Are you including jQuery in your page? Why aren't you using [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)?

Comment: can you make this clearer please? where are the #thumb_list and #full_size divs? Is there a website we can see?

Comment: Ahh jesus, I knew there was a better way to do this...thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your ID's don't match.

In your HTML you have `toggle_thumbs`, but in your code you have `toggle_thumb`.

---

If all you're doing is hiding and showing, you can greatly simplify your code like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/xTPU8/2/

```
$(function() {
    var $elems = $('#toggle_full').hide()
        .add('#toggle_thumb').click(function() {
            $elems.toggle();
    });
});​
```

**EDIT:** Made it even a little more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `return false;` in your `.click()` delegate to prevent the browser from navigating to '#' (jumps to top of page).

You can also simplify your JS but putting both of your link bindings in the same, and using `hide()` and `show()` as already suggested. The end result would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {   

        $('#toggle_full').click(function() {         
            $('#full_size').show();
            $('#thumb_list').hide();
            return false;
        });


        $('#toggle_thumb').click(function() {            
            $('#thumb_list').show();
            $('#full_size').hide();
            return false;
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: linking to # shouldn't be a problem for jquery