# Hide and show 2 div in a same button in javaScript

Tags: javascript

When page loaded, div1 (graph) should be display always and when click on the button the div2 (video) should be displayed and the div1 should disappear. Only one button should be used. Is it possible to do like this?

```css
#graph{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: rgb(172, 206, 6);
margin-left: 220px;
}
#video{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: rgb(9, 182, 223);
margin-left: 400px;
margin-top: -100px;
}
#video-btn {
background-color: rgb(64, 186, 195);
width: 100px;
height: 30px;
color: white;
margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<button id="video-btn">Button</button>

<div id="graph">Graph content</div>
<div id="video">Video content</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Toggle div question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587607/toggle-div-question)

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV what does it matter which server side language the OP is using? This question is frontend related.

Answer (score 2):

Simple version. (You can adjust sizes and positions as you want.)

CSS

```
#graph {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background:#eaeaea;
}
#video {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background:#888888;
    display:none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id = "graph"></div>
<div id = "video"></div>
<button id = "button">Click Me</button>
```

JS

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $('#graph, #video').toggle();
});
```

Fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/fcvqnrey/)

Answer (score 0):

## Yes

### Vanilla Js

```
var btn = document.getElementById('video-btn'),
    graph = document.getElementById('graph');

btn.onclick = function () {
    graph.style.display = 'none';
};
```

Here is the **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4wv4mhob/)**.

### jQuery

You will need to look add a click event to `#video-btn`, and run the `hide()` method on `#graph`.

```js
$('#video-btn').click(function (){
    $('#graph').hide();
});
```

```css
#graph{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: rgb(172, 206, 6);
margin-left: 220px;
}
#video{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: rgb(9, 182, 223);
margin-left: 400px;
margin-top: -100px;
}
#video-btn {
background-color: rgb(64, 186, 195);
width: 100px;
height: 30px;
color: white;
margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="video-btn">Button</button>

<div id="graph">Graph content</div>
<div id="video">Video content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var sw = true;
  $('#video-btn').click(function (){
    if(sw) {
      $('#graph').hide();
      $('#video').show(); 
      sw=false;
    }
    else {
        $('#video').hide(); 
        $('#graph').show();
        sw=true;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

can you use Jquery

```js
function btn(){
$('#graph').hide();
$('#video').show();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function showVideo(){
  if(document.getElementById('video').style.display=='none'){
    document.getElementById('video').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('graph').style.display='none';
  }else{
    document.getElementById('video').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('graph').style.display='block';
  }
}
```

```css
#graph{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(172, 206, 6);
    margin-left: 220px;
}
#video{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(9, 182, 223);
    margin-left: 400px;
}
#video-btn {
    background-color: rgb(64, 186, 195);
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<button id="video-btn" onclick='showVideo()'>Button</button>

<div id="graph">Graph content</div>
<div id="video" style='display: none'>Video content</div>
```

I think this is what you are looking for.
Check it and ask me.